# JS - ID - Rails 4 - Compare two ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I would like my Jquery to select a `data` class with attribute `data-id` (which has a class `colapse-project`) only if his `data-id` is different from the PP class `data-id`.

I'm stucked here:

```
 if ($(PP).attr("data-id")!=$(data).attr("data-id").hasClass('colapse-project')){

                alert('different')
            }
```

Comment: Why not render the `id` into another attribute, like `data-id`?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your comment. I don't think it will solve the problem in my case because I also use <%= render_project.id %> in the parent div.

Comment: Or can you explain more ?

Comment: I don't see how that can prevent this simple solution and there is a severe lack of information for any further explaination. Try sticking with "I want X, I tried Y, I got Z".

Comment: @NathanSchwarz You really need to provide more information. Like D-side said, clearly describe your question in detail along with as much of your code as you can share (so that we know what you have tried) and the output of the code that you are seeing or any error if you seeing those. Only then can we help you or provide some useful information.

Comment: Yes of course ! Actually I made an other post which concern the same issue but I was wondering if there was a way to compare the id's as I said in this post. You can check the other post here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828783/rails-4-js-id-hide-a-div-with-id-trick

Comment: @D-side I rendered the id in an other attribute like you said and now I've got this error : "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).data(...).click is not a function"

Comment: I do not see anything like that in the question.

Comment: @NathanSchwarz look up the return type of `data` in jQuery docs.

Comment: @D-side Ok so now i'm back to the first issue.

Comment: And you still fail to provide enough information to reproduce this. What is `PP`? What is `data`? What error message shows up, at least? Well, at least stop comparing mismatching types, `hasClass` returns a boolean, `attr` returns a string (most of the time?).